# Separating objects causing material disconnection issue

Tags: objects

I am very new to Blender but recently picked it up and forced myself to learn the program. Currently, I have taken a logo of a friends company, sketched it out via bezeir curve and made it 3D. Now I am making an animation where the different parts come together to complete the logo. I have the logo looking somewhat metallic and satisfied thus far with the results. Now, the issue lies with when I have taken a part of the logo, separated it from the main mesh/object (which constitutes the logo). Reason being, I noticed for a keyframe to register a moving part from my logo the individual parts had to be separated. However, when the parts come together each separated part’s material does not look unified with the overall logo/object. As each small part has a weird swirl.

Hopefully that made some sense as I am new to all of this… If this is a common problem I would love to know how to get around it.

Thank you!

Comment: A screenshot of your problem would be very helpful in figuring out what is wrong.

Comment: Start with the assembled logo, duplicate it and keep that safe in another layer or 

equivalent for 2.8. Break up the model by separating it's component parts and before 

moving any, keyframe their (assembled) locations, rotations, etc. Animate these so they 

drift apart, rotating and so forth.  Reverse those keyframes (automatically) in the 

dopesheet so they come back exactly as they were. If you then want to move that around as a whole, parent everything to an Empty and move the Empty, or simply switch back to 

the duplicate. (the switch-back will be indetectable)

Comment: Added to the above - your 'swirling' effect may well be two or more surfaces overlapping. It's called "Z fighting" in Blender speak.  Both surfaces occupying the same location.

Comment: Wow thank you guys. I really appreciate the feedback. I’ll make the recommended changes tomorrow and will report back. I’ll also take a screenshot of the issue ASAP. Thanks again!

Comment: Just in case normal calculation is the problem,  you could check out answers like [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/109010/35559)

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the issue at hand: https://ibb.co/NxsyKBm